# What is the best way to authorize calls to the shopify Admin API within a webhook handler

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am creating a webhook handler (within aws lambda) for my shopify app.

*Note: I'm using eventbridge to receive webhooks, but i believe the concept is the same.*

When a customer creates a new order this webhook will be called, and from within my webhook handler i would like to make an authenticated request to the Nodejs `@shopify/shopify-api` Admin API.

My question is,  what is the best way to do this?

For example,  how do i use the details from the webhook event to create a session which i can then use to make requests to the Admin API?

eg;

```
const product = await shopify.rest.Product.find({session, id: '7504536535062'});

product.title = 'A new title';

await product.save({
  update: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the webhook comes from a store! So you know the *.myshopify.com
2. you saved an access token with the same store name in your DB

So now you can use the access token against the store, to make API calls within the scope of permissions granted when the store installed the App.